# Automapper database lookups?

Tags: c#, automapper

Is there another way to handle calling the database when needing to lookup values for mapping?  It just seems ugly to have database calls within mapping logic.  How else is this handled?

For example, a table stores a SEXID so using the resolver below I can do something like this

```
CreateMap<StagingPerson, Person>()
  .ForMember( dest => dest.SEXID, 
     m => m.ResolveUsing<SexLookupResolver>().FromMember( src => src.Gender ) );         

public class SexLookupResolver : ValueResolver<string, int>
{
protected override int ResolveCore( string source )
{
  int id = -1;
  if (source == "Male")
     id = dataAccess.GetGenderByString("M");
  else if(source == "Female")
     id = dataAccess.GetGenderByString("F");
  else if(source == "?")
     id = dataAccess.GetGenderByString("?");
  else
     id = dataAccess.GetGenderByString("?");
  return id;
}
}
```

DataAccess:

```
public int GetGenderByString(string gender)
{
  string sql = "select sexid from Sexes where sex = '" + gender "'";
  int sexid = .....
  ......
  return sexid;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this via adding another field to the class to store the string version of the sex.  The mapping is changed to map to the string and the SEXID field is ignored and set later during a DAL operation.

```
CreateMap<StagingPerson, Person>()
  .ForMember( dest => dest.SexString, u => u.MapFrom( src => src.Sex) )
  .ForMember( dest => dest.SEXID, u.Ignore() ) );

/// The source class
public class StagingPerson
{
  /// holds "M", "F", "U", "?", etc
  public string Gender {get;set;}
}
```

and

```
/// the destination class
public class Person
{
  public int SEXID {get;set;}

  // New property to store the source string value
  // looked up in the Data Access Layer to determine the sexId
  public string SexString {get;set;}
}
```